# Matlab class incrementing static number

Tags: arrays, matlab, object, static

I've created an object with an Id property.
I'm trying to create an array which will automatically fill the Id property according to the location in the array or a static incrementing int starting from 1.

How do I implement this?

I tried to create a constructor with id as input, but writing
myArr(100) = myObj throws an error.
How do I initialize this also with the id (using static id or any other way).

Thanks

Comment: Please post matlab error and relevant code sample from constructor of myObj...

Answer (score 0):

I know this is only a partial solution, but suppose you have a matrix M where the first index is the ID value, then here is what you can do:

```
M(:,1) = 1:size(M,1)
```

Or if you have a matrix M where the first column needs to be added with ID values:

```
M = [1:size(M,1) M]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
classdef a_class < handle    

properties
    id
end

methods
    function obj = a_class(size_of_matrix)   

        if nargin == 0 %default constructor
            %something constant. Do not try to place counter here.

        else
            if numel(size_of_matrix)==1 
                size_of_matrix = [size_of_matrix size_of_matrix];
            end;

            obj(size_of_matrix(:)) = a_class; % Preallocate object array

            id_cell = num2cell(1:prod(size_of_matrix));
            [obj(1:prod(size_of_matrix)).id] = id_cell{:};

        end
    end
end
end
```

I'm afraid, this is the best possible solution.

Note you can't define a counter in default constructor, and then allocate an array, as, in fact, it would be called only once.

PS
They use even more naive for-based syntax in [official tutorial](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/matlab_oop/creating-object-arrays.html)...